# makeコマンドでビルド中に「make: execvp: /bin/sh: Argument list too long」エラーが発生

Tags: linux, bash, shellscript, makefile

makeコマンドにてビルドした際にエラーが発生しています。
Linuxの設定が悪いのか、Makefileの作りが悪いのか、シェルの作りが悪いのか判断できないため、ご教示頂きたいです。

### 環境

- raspberry pi 3 B+
- openSUSE 64bit
- Makefileとその中で呼び出しているシェルスクリプト

  - Makefile
    https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/Makefile
  - シェルスクリプト
    https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/scripts/goListFiles.sh

### エラー内容

```
Creating .build/goshim.tar.bz2
make: execvp: /bin/sh: Argument list too long
make: *** [Makefile:316: .build/goshim.tar.bz2] Error 127
```

### エラー発生箇所

```
GOSHIM_DEPS = $(shell ./scripts/goListFiles.sh $(PKGNAME)/core/chaincode/shim)
orderer: $(BUILD_DIR)/bin/orderer

$(BUILD_DIR)/goshim.tar.bz2: $(GOSHIM_DEPS)
        @echo "Creating $@"
        @tar -jhc -C $(GOPATH)/src $(patsubst $(GOPATH)/src/%,%,$(GOSHIM_DEPS)) > $@
```

### 試したこと

#### １．シェルの引数をxargsで分割してみる

同じエラーが発生し、解決しませんでした。
下記に`@tar -jhc -C $(GOPATH)/src $(patsubst $(GOPATH)/src/%,%,$(GOSHIM_DEPS))`を置き換えたMakefileの一文を記載します。

```
@./scripts/goListFiles.sh $(PKGNAME)/core/chaincode/shim | sed s#$(GOPATH)/src/##g | xargs tar -jhc -C $(GOPATH)/src > $@
```

#### ２．シェル引数の上限値を上げる

下記で表示される値をあげてみましたが解決しませんでした。

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

#### ３．ARMでなく、x64のubuntu, centOSでビルド

こちらは問題なくビルドが成功しました。

Answer (score 1):

GNU tarではアーカイブに追加するファイルを引数に指定する代わりに、`-T`オプションで指定したファイルから読み込ませることができます。

Raspberry piのtarがこのオプションをサポートしていれば、ファイルのリストを適当なファイルに書き出して、tarの`-T`オプションでそのファイルを指定してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: tarコマンドというよりは、どうもシェル内でエラーが発生している様です。(findした結果、ファイル数が多すぎる?https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/scripts/goListFiles.sh#L30)

makeファイルはあきらめて手で対象のファイルをtarコマンドで固めることにします。